# I want to fix the text in a box to the right in a column and the image to the left

Tags: html, css

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

.timeline:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
  /* Added z-index to move the line behind the year circles */
}

.timeline-item {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 100px 0;
}

.timeline-year {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  /* Increased top position to make space for the year circle */
  left: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
  /* Added z-index to move the year circles in front of the line */
  justify-content: center;
}

.timeline-content {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  z-index: 2;
  /* Added z-index to move the content boxes in front of the line and year circles */
}

.timeline-content h3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.timeline-content p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline-image {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right: 50px;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.timeline-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.timeline-year::before {
  content: attr(data-year);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.timeline-year:hover::before {
  /* Added hover effect to year circles */
  content: "";
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-year" data-year="2000"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <div class="timeline-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
      <h3>title1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-year" data-year="2001"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <div class="timeline-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
      <h3>title2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-item">
    <div class="timeline-year" data-year="2002"></div>
    <div class="timeline-content">
      <div class="timeline-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
      <h3>title3</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but the result is like in the image I posted:
[image]

I want the texts I write to be aligned on the right side of the image one under the other, not like a row, not side by side and I want the image to be aligned on the left side of the box without getting squeezed, without changing its size. But I couldn't do it. Can you help me?

Comment: `not like a row, not side by side` (what?). Can you provide an image of what you want?

Comment: in the image, the paragraphs (texts) are side by side as you can see. I want the paragraphs (texts) to be one below the other. Like in this link: https://fikritakip.co/alim-gucunun-20-yili/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `p` elements are side by side is because they are direct children of a flex parent.  In this case `timeline-content` is the flex parent.

Does wrapping the text in their own div get you closer to what you want?

```
<div class="timeline-content">
  <div class="timeline-image"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></div>
  <h3>title1</h3>
  <div class="timeline-text">  
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

This change gets them back to stacking because the `p` elements are no longer direct children of a flex parent.  Instead the `div` wrapper is the direct child of a flex parent.

Edit: Per your comment, I have added a class to the wrapper I added and then we can add these styles to your CSS

```
.timeline-text{
  flex-basis:0;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

The flex-basis will keep the wrapper from trying to squish the image, and the flex-grow will allow the text wrapper to take up all the available space outside of the image.

Comment: Yes, thank you so much. But there are some other problems. When the number of characters in the text increases, and therefore the number of lines increases, the size of the image on the left side decreasing, the image squeezing. You can see this by adding new text to the text in the <p> tag. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I added the class `timeline-text` to the wrapper div I created above, and added these styles:

`.timeline-text{
  flex-basis:0;
  flex-grow:1;
}`

Setting flex basis of 0 will keep the text area from trying to squish the image.  `flex-grow:1` will allow the text wrapper to take up all the space that the image isn't using.